# Snippet's não estão a funcionar

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, stack-snippets

Hoje, tenho notado que os *snippet's* não estão a funcionar como deveriam:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Ontem por vários momentos todo o conteúdo estático do *site* estava com problema e em alguns momentos caia tudo. Pode estar instável hoje ainda. https://twitter.com/GABeech/status/560570053448302592

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247717/500-internal-server-error-in-stacksnippets-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a few issues during some upgrades last night.  We have since resolved this but thanks for your report!

[PT]

> Tivemos alguns problemas durante alguns *upgrades* na noite passada.
>   Nós já resolvemos isso, mas obrigado pelo seu *report*!